# Copying a Magento 2 Site to New Domain 'Remembers' Old Site

Tags: magento2, database, cache, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I have **copied a Magento 2 site** from a **test domain** (testing.mytest.co.uk) to a **live domain** (mylive.co.uk). It has come time to upgrade the Magento version (2.2.5 to 2.2.6) and I receive the following **error during readiness check**:

> ```
>     Found non-writable path(s):
> /var/www/vhosts/mytest.co.uk/testing.mytest.co.uk/var/.htaccess
> ```

The reason it's not writable is because that is not the domain that relates to where the site is now. It's as if it is 'remembering' where it used to be? And I am unsure where this needs changing.

*env.php and core_config_data* have been updated.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Have you cleared static content and updated the base url in core_config_data?

Comment: do you have var folder on magento root? with .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes there is a .htaccess file in var folder in magento 2

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.